# Set Listview height which is inside an Scrollview with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I referred many sites, and Finally i am using the below method for setting the listview height which is present inside the Scrillview.

```
  public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0));
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        }
        System.out.println("list item height setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren :"+totalHeight);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

This code is working in eclipse. now i converted my project from eclipse to android studio. Now the same code is giving wrong height.

built.gradle(app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.teclever.homecareapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

in eclipse the target is 22 now i changed into 23. But why the same code is not working now. I tried with 22 also. Both are not working. So please help anyone.

Comment: what does wrong height means??

Comment: if 4 items are there, then it gives 356 in eclipse. For same page if i run by using android studio its giving 2212.

Comment: are you testing in the same device?

Comment: yes same device with android 4.2.2

Comment: Is your layout not showing properly or you require total height somewhere in your code

Comment: Layout is not showing properly. i have given the listview height as wrapcontent.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of it.

Comment: Screen shot link :  http://postimg.org/image/m7niu632z/

Comment: I don't see any problem with the screen

Comment: There are more content below. but it is showing that much empty spaces that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This method always work for me:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * 
        (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

Comment: This is the same method he has used

Comment: 'listItem.measure(0, 0);' line giving NPE.